# How to fetch grand children table with Hibernate annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have 3 tables working as LetterOfCredit has many ProformatInvoice which has many PurchaseOrder.

I would like to get in my entity LetterOfCredit the list of all the PurchaseOrder linked via ProformatInvoice.

In SQL it looks like :

```
SELECT *
FROM purchase_order
JOIN proformat_invoice pi ON pi.id = pi_id
JOIN letter_of_credit lc ON lc.id = pi.lc_id
WHERE lc_id = 3;
```

But in LetterOfCredit.java, I tried to use proformat_invoice as a jointable but I get an empty list....

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name="proformat_invoice",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="lc_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "pi_id")
)
private List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders;
```

Could you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
We can fetch the grand children efficiently by using hibernate annotation ---- @OneToMany( mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY ).
So in this case this will not give an exception if its unable to fetch the sub children till session is open. 
We can manually pull the sub children by using the getters in our code without getting any exception , as we have already told the compiler that it will be lazy loading because there are child elements and there sub child elements.
```

Comment: @OneToMany( mappedBy = "proformatInvoice", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders; give me an empty list too

Comment: Your comment seems to come from an article or documentation. May I have the link?

Comment: its my comment in my words , not linked anywhere.